# Confusion over L2 Spaces

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I'm new to stochastic calculus, so hopefully this isn't too silly of a question.

**Setup:**

---

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space on which a Brownian motion $W_t$ is defined (and adapted) and fix $T>0$.  Let $\mathcal{L}^2(W)$ denote the Hilbert space of all progressively measurable stochastic processes $\phi$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$ which satisfy
$$
\|\phi\|_{\mathcal{L}^2(W)}\triangleq \mathbb{E}\left[
\int_0^T \phi_s^2 d[W]_s
\right]<\infty.
$$
Let $H$ denote the Hilbert subspace
$$
\left\{
X \in L^2_{\mathbb{P}\otimes m}(\mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{B}([0,\infty)):\,
(\exists \phi \in \mathcal{L}^2(W) ) \, X_t = \int_0^{T} \phi_s dW_s
\right\}
,
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\infty)$.

**Question:**

---

Does there exist a bi-Lipschitz function (or even better, a linear isometry) between $L^2_{\mu}([0,\infty))$ and either of these two spaces:

- ${\mathcal{L}^2(W)}$?
- $H$?

*Where $\mu$ is a Borel measure, defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$?*

Comment: Don’t know much about functional analysis, because I just start to learn it. But we can view $\mathcal L^2(W)$ as an ordinary $L^2$ space, namely $$L^2(\Omega\times\mathbb R_+,\mathcal P, dPd[W]_s)$$ where $\mathcal P$ is the progressive $\sigma-$field on $\Omega\times\mathbb R_+$ and $dPd[W]_s$ refers to the finite measure that assigns the mass $$E\left[\int_0^\infty 1_A(\omega,s)d[W]_s\right]$$ to a set $A\in\mathcal P$. Hope it will help...

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  But what is the isometry between these two spaces?  (This is part of what's confusing me).

Comment: Any two separable and infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometric. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: True, but I'm wondering if there is an explicit "simple" isomorphism, beyond mapping the coefficients of an an orthonormal basis to and from $\ell^2$... For example, something like $f\mapsto f(W)$?

Comment: Is the  $t$ in your definition of $\mathcal L^2(W)$ and $H$ fixed?

Comment: I can see some of the ambiguity..  I edited the question so that $T>0$ is fixed and $t$ is just a dummy variable.